# Why IE 9 not supporting JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to make a function for checking file size and extension on run time, I have done it  and working properly on all browser except ie 9. Can anyone let me know where the problem?

### Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showFileSize() {
    var input, file;

    // (Can't use `typeof FileReader === "function"` because apparently
    // it comes back as "object" on some browsers. So just see if it's there
    // at all.)
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        bodyAppend("p", "The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
        return;
    }

    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');

   if (!input.files[0]) {
        bodyAppend("p", "Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
        file = input.files[0];
        var sFileName = file.name;
        var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();

        bodyAppend("p", "File Type " + sFileExtension + " is " + file.size + " bytes in size");
    }
}

function bodyAppend(tagName, innerHTML) {
    var elm;

    elm = document.createElement(tagName);
    elm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
}
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<form action='#' onsubmit="return false;">
<input type='file' id='fileinput'>
<input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Save' onclick='showFileSize();'>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you seriously asking ***why*** IE9 does not support the `FileReader`, and why it was only implented in IE10? What do you want us to answer to that? Because Bill said no, because .. microsoft, because the didn't !

Comment: Ok, I removed my comment but I think it provides usefulness to this question. **IE sucks**, and like @adeneo stated - it has not yet been implemented in that outdated browser version.

Comment: @adeneo yes i'm, But how can solve the issue, Is this possible to solve the issue....?

Comment: @urbz - *`"not yet been implemented"`*, I think that train has pretty much left the station, and there's no going back

Comment: Let me rephrase and please have indulgence of morning fatigue - _it will not be implemented_. @Ayaz a probable workaround could be [**THIS**](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader) but otherwise IE9 does not support HTML5 File API, including `FileReader` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 does not support HTML5 File API, including `FileReader()` ..

A possible workaround would be to polyfill, the solution below uses Flash to provide access to the filesystem on browsers that don't support the File APIs (IE and Safari), **but it does not support drag-n-drop**.

- [**`Link here`**](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader)
- [**`Reference on why FileReader does not work for IE9`**](http://caniuse.com/filereader)

Answer (score 0):

Instead, clone the input, place the clone where the original is, and move the original into a hidden form. You might have to use an iframe for this.

This would certainly work but involves some coding.