# How to preview an image before upload on IE8 - Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am stuck on one simple task that works well on all browsers - Image preview

I tested the FileREader & Form Data API which works great.
I also used Ie8 filter which works but requires a change in IE's default settings.

The known solution is: Create an invisible iframe which contains a file upload button. Once the user upload the image on the parent page, the event is clone inside the invisible form, and the form submitted. On the return page of the iframe, to display the image - extract the url and append it to my main preview image div. I want to avoid this complicated alternative..

Is there any other way to make this work?

PLease note what i tested here:

```
    function ie8(imgFile) {

        var newPreview = $(".article__image");
        newPreview.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = imgFile.value;
        newPreview.style.width = "600px";
        newPreview.style.height = "400px";
}


function nonie8(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.js-ugc-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is actually almost a duplicate of the question posted right below yours, only a few minutes ago -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197067/why-ie-9-not-supporting-javascript-function

Comment: It is not a duplicate - The post before mentions filereader only. Here i mention the other options i tested. FormData & ie8 filter

Comment: I said "almost", you're both struggling with the FileReader and basically need to polyfill it for older browsers.

Comment: I know about the flash polyfill. Cant use it :(